# Referencing and Inserting ObjectId's from one collection to another as an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have two collections. One to store all the user Details and another to store movies. I have a user_id field which has the objectId of the user who uploads it in the movie collection.
Now I need to store all the movie ObjectId's as a array in the corresponding user collection. Like one to many relationship.
say,
I have some movie documents :

```
     [{
          'id' : '1',
          'title' : 'Pk',
          'user_id' : '25'
      },
     {
          'id' : '2',
          'title' : 'Master',
          'user_id' : '25'
     }]
```

In user collection, I want to store all the Movie_id's as a array to the corresponding user.

```
      { 
         'user_id' : '25',
         'user_name' : 'john',
          'Movie_ids' : ['1','2']
      }
```

How can I achieve this using mongodb and express.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- `$lookup` does what you want (see mongodb documentation is very good)
- `$map` is used to keep only the ids in the array

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XE8aAXXtxSM)

```js
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "movies",
      "localField": "user_id",
      "foreignField": "user_id",
      "as": "movies"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "movies": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$movies",
          "in": "$$this.id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Got it ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure if this is entirely what you are looking for but you can use javascript function .filter on the movie object to get all the movies with user_id=25 and then map the id's of those movies to a new array like this:

```
let movies = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "pk",
    "user_id": "25"
},{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Master",
    "user_id": "25"
}]
let user = {
  "id": "25",
  "name": "john"
}

let sortedMovies = movies.filter(movie => movie.user_id  === user.id).map(movie => movie.id);
user.movieIDs = sortedMovies;
```

A link to test the code: https://playcode.io/816962/

Comment: How to implement this, if there are many users?

Comment: Can't we do this using mongodb referencing? Like in user model, movieIds : [{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie'}]

Comment: I would probably make a function that takes in the movies object and user.id as parameter, like function `addMoviesToUser(movies, userID){ };`
But you can also create an array in the user object called movie_ids (which would be empty at first) and then push the id of the movie whenever a user uploads a new movie.
Like `user["movie_ids"].push(movies.id);`

EDIT: I'm so sorry, I didn't see that you wanted to do it only by using mongoDB